# 24 года.. стоит ли начинать учиться? возможно ли осуществить самостоятельно?

Tags: веб-программирование

В общем дело обстоит так:
Всю свою жизнь испытывал огромный интерес всему что связано с компьютерами, но кроме как качать софт с инета и пользоваться им - ничему не научился, так как пока был маленьким не хотел читать, а после уже не было времени. Тяга в этом направлении никуда не пропадала - все так же ковырялся в своем ПК, восстанавливал друзьям работоспособность их компов и много много всего в этом духе. Но ничем конкретным так и не занимался. Теперь, уже, заканчивая институт МЧС, понимаю, что это конечно хорошо, но определенно не мое. Очень хотелось бы писать какие-либо программы, хотя бы для себя, ну или еще лучше - хоть не большой, но доход от этого иметь. Будь у меня сейчас такая возможность - с удовольствием пошел бы учиться в ВУЗ с такой направленностью. Но возможности, к сожалению нет.
И, вот, на фоне всего вышесказанного хочу спросить совета понимающих людей: стоит ли мне, в 24 года (возможно уже поздно начинать), заняться изучением языка(-ов) программирования. Может ли у меня что-то получиться? И, вообще, что вы думаете о самообучении - реально ли самому достаточно хорошо овладеть языком(-ми) программирования?
И если такой вариант возможен, то с чего начать? За какой язык взяться, чтобы не упустить основ, но в то же время более быстро усвоить эти основы и уже двигаться дальше.

Comment: "учится никогда не поздно" (с) кто-то

Даже отучившись в институте на нужной специальности не тгарантий, что вы станете программистом или научитесь писать код. Главное заточить мозги, а потом уже выучить какой-то язык (первое важнее). если у вас есть предрасположенность, то это упрощает задачу раза в 2.

p.s. результат во многом зависит от того сколько времени в день вы можете тратить на обучение, если много учите сразу фундаментальные языки C#, Java и им подобные. Если мало то я б порекомендовал `javascript+html` сможете написать какой-то сайтик для себя и оценить свои перспективы на будущее

Comment: советую начать с с++, в инете очень много материалов а потом уже JAVA, JS. А html, css освоите максимум за неделю потом постепенно можно углублять. Категорически не советую видео уроки по ЯП.

Comment: >советую начать с с++, в инете очень много материалов а потом уже JAVA, JS

почему сразу не с Java или JS? Зачем вообще С++, если заниматься впоследствии фронтендом на JS? Или наоборот - зачем JS, если знаешь С++?

Comment: @jmu, Вы серьезно считаете, что можно "заточить мозги" **до** изучения хоть одного языка?

IMHO они затачиваются в процессе написания программ, а если хоть какой-то язык еще не выучен, то никакую программу написать просто не удастся.

Т.о. язык тут все-таки первичен.

Comment: изучения языка означает обучение алгоритмизации (паралельно), поэтому главное научится мыслить правильно, - составлять алгоритмы, анализировать, развивать логическое мышление. а перенести алгоритм в код не так уж сложно. если следовать вашей логике получается что выучил язык - научился программировать, а как же те люди которые написали этот язык, видимо они уже умели программировать до этого !? понятно что без знания языка далеко не уедешь но если базы нету, то будет очень туго, вы уж мне поверьте у меня тут есть несколько живых примеров пытающихся освоить программирование :) и им за 30

Comment: @jmu, невозможно внятно изложить алгоритм на естественном языке, если не знать реальный язык программирования (а желательно несколько, причем разноплановых, например: C, Java, Shell, SQL, Lisp ...). 

Естественно, в процессе проектирования (пусть даже только "в уме") алгоритм досконально не записывается на конкретном языке, но возможности, присущие языкам, которые предполагается использовать при реализации, обязательно учитываются.

Ну, а на вопрос:

     те люди которые написали этот язык, видимо они уже умели программировать до этого !?

очевидный ответ -- *ДА** (причем, уже на нем).

Answer (score 10):

В принципе 24 года - возраст не такой уж критичный. Конечно,  энное количество времени вам придется потратить на то, чтобы вашими знаниями и умениями можно было заинтересовать какого-то работодателя, то есть собственно на учебу. Это не сиюминутный процесс (несмотря на увещевания всяких там авторов дешевых видеокурсов), и займет он как минимум несколько месяцев (а скорее всего, не меньше года-двух).  Поэтому самое главное, что вам нужно помнить - это то, что у вас не так много времени, а следовательно, необходимо забыть о всяческой лени. 
Кроме того, в процессе обучения постарайтесь искать и выполнять какую-то фрилансерскую работу - сразу на постоянное сотрудничество вас скорее всего не возьмут, а с помощью фриланса вы сможете обрести хотя бы какой-то опыт.

Что касается самообучения - это вполне реально, хотя и несколько сложнее - постоянно нужно заставлять себя, подпиныать, мотивировать. Не всем это удается. К тому же собственные ошибки далеко не всегда бывают заметны. Однако далеко не все профессиональные программисты заканчивали ВУЗ по соответствующей специальности, а следовательно, ничего невозможного в самообучении нет. Во всяком случае, программисты в плане самообучения имеют определенное преимущество - для этого достаточно компьютера и интернета (ну и головы с мозгами, разумеется). Скажем, "самообучиться" таким макаром на нейрохирурга вряд ли получится

Кстати насчет самообучения, опрос на Хабре:

[image]

Выводы, думаю, очевидны

Comment: А меня одного напрягает сумма результатов в 144% ?! :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev думаю, тут ничего удивительного - можно было выбирать несколько вариантов.. Один вид образования не исключает другого, и, скажем, часть знаний человек мог получить в вузе, другую часть - при самообучении

Answer (score 2):

По возрасту - самое то. У вас как раз мозги уже более взрослые, чем у подростка, и если есть желание и самодисциплина, то все сложится крайне хорошо.
На мой взгляд, вам нужно определиться в нескольких моментах:

1. Вы хотите научиться писать
       программы в какой области? Варианты:
       стационарные ПК, планшеты и
       смартфоны, веб. От этого зависит
       выбор языков.
2. Сразу нужно понять,
       что не существует того
       окончательного набора знаний, после
       которого вы можете остановиться и
       сказать, что вы состоявшийся
       программист. Вы будете читать книги
       и изучать новые технологии всю
       жизнь, потому что развитие
       технологий опережает скорость
       усвоения знаний.
3. Аналогично нужно
       понять, что 1 языка вам не хватит.
       Если, например, вы выбираете веб
       (создание сайтов), в ам нужно будет изучить (постепенно): HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, MySQL, базовое администрирование linux-серверов (например, на CentOS - установка панелей управления и необходимого ПО) и т.д. (список можно продолжить). Какое бы вы направление ни выбрали, это будет система взаимосвязанных технологий. Чем выше будет ваш уровень, тем больше будет эта система.
4. Вы будете изучать технологии самостоятельно (по книгам) - или же у вас есть человек, который может стать наставником? Если вы можете обучаться самостоятельно, это огромный плюс. Фишка в том, что в вашем возрасте обычно воли и мотивации больше, чем у подростков, поэтому это вполне реально. Также если вам позволяют финансы, можно пойти на курсы. Вы сэкономите, действительно, много времени, но потратите больше денег. В зависимости от уровня и продолжительности курсов по 1 языку они вам обойдутся от нескольких тысяч рублей до 150 тыс.
   При выборе пути обучения по книгам / статьям важно выбрать достойные. Это сложно сделать, когда у вас нет опыта. Поэтому определитесь с технологиями (см. п. 1) и задайте вопрос на проф. форуме относительно хороших книг. Если вы выбираете веб, то можете написать мне личное сообщение, я дам вам список тех, которые считаю наиболее достойными и адекватными.

В целом, могу сказать, что все целиком и полностью зависит от вас. По опыту - если у вас действительно сильная мотивация и есть голова на плечах, вы умеете себя дисциплинировать (а не идти пить пиво по первому зову приятеля) - за год усердного изучения вы добьетесь очень высоких результатов. За два вы станете профи. Это справедливо даже в том случае, если вы все будете изучать сами и не пойдете на курсы.

Comment: >По возрасту - самое то

не соглашусь.  К 24 годам уже неплохо бы иметь хотя бы год опыта работы (при не очень благоприятном стечении обстоятельств, когда, скажем, программист в течение учебы в институте нигде не работал, а затем ушел в армию, и начал работать только с 23 лет).  Если бы это было "самое то", то все бы начинали учиться программировать именно с этого возраста. Не стану утверждать, что 24 года - это очень много, но если есть возможность начинать раньше, то лучше начать раньше.

Comment: Можно всегда придумать тот вариант, который будет лучше для 24 лет.:) У кого-то уже заработан миллион долларов. Но это не отменяет того факта, что в 24 года человек уже обладает способностями видеть суть и обобщать информацию гораздо лучше, чем подросток или даже юноша.
Начинать раньше у автора поста возможности уже нет. А вот если начать сейчас, то возможность стать профи очень даже большая, только это я и хотел сказать.

Answer (score 2):

> И, вот, на фоне всего вышесказанного хочу спросить совета понимающих людей: стоит ли мне, в 24 года (возможно уже поздно начинать), заняться изучением языка(-ов) программирования. Может ли у меня что-то получиться?

Люди в 35 начинают и преуспевают. Так что дерзайте.

> И, вообще, что вы думаете о самообучении - реально ли самому достаточно хорошо овладеть языком(-ми) программирования?

Реально. Сужу по себе: единственное что - базовые алгоритмы мне в свое время растолковали друзья; остальное сам.

> И если такой вариант возможен, то с чего начать?

Имхо, с javascript'а начните пожалуй. Хотя наверное и другие пойдут.

> За какой язык взяться, чтобы не упустить основ, но в то же время более быстро усвоить эти основы и уже двигаться дальше.

Я начинал с Pascal'я.

Вообще могу порекомендовать вам для старта обучения этот ресурс http://www.codecademy.com, ну или другие похожие.

Answer (score 1):

В 24 начинать нужно правильно.
1.Linux,bash.
2.Python 3,GNU C/C++
3.Английский
4.Математика для программиста.

Answer (score 0):

главное чтоб не только желание а тяга была. и придетца отмести все остальное иначе времени на развитие не хватит

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же не поздно, если вы умеете пользоваться поисковиком и правильно формулировать свой вопрос, тогда всё впорядке. :) Лучше всего месяцок ознакомиться с Паскалем и затем перейти на  C/C++, и где то через 100500 велосипедов и надоедливых задачек без красивого интерфейса и особенной значимости своих калькуляторов и вывода на экран текстовых сообщений начинать немножко поглядывать на такие как C# и Java, сравнить их посмотреть, что общего и какая специфика у каждого из них. Тем самым вы уже поймете, что решая какую либо задачу, можно выбрать язык предназначенный именно для нее.Мне давно кто то сказал, что нужно научиться программировать, а с языком уже разобраться не долго. Тогда я не понимал, как это так, вот и вы постигайте истину и не ленитесь. Советую начать с книги "Лафоре ООП С++" (делать все примеры, задачи и не копипастить, а переписывать чужой код символ за символом) и затем "Веревка достаточной длины чтобы выстрелить себе в ногу".